# Removing console.log in iOS app for production version

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, console

I would like to keep the console.log in test builds, but in production builds I want them to be removed. Where can I do that? Do I need to create code for this or I can set any settings in Info.plist?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

If you are using
`print("Log")`

change to
`debugPrint("Log")`